# Probabilities of this blackjack hybrid

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently trying to study a hybrid / simplified version of Black Jack but as i am not as good with probabilities i am hoping that i could receive some advice about the probabilities behind the game.

The rules of the game:

The three face cards are all worth 10 points, just like the real BlackJack. The Ace card has a behavior where it gets the value of 11/1. To understand the logic in this hybrid, simply assume that Ace has a value of 11 however if the total goes over 21, minus 10 from the total.

All cards are chosen randomly by a computer and hence the same cards can be repeated and the probability of selection of a particular card is independent of the probability of the cards that came before it.

All other cards have values 1-9, same as their real number. However the gameplay is modified and simplified

The player starts the game and gets two random cards. If the total of these cards adds up to 21 (I.e one ace and one face card) the player immediately wins. If the total is not 21, the player is free to draw as many cards as possible but if the total goes over 21, he loses. Once he's satisfied with the total, he 'stands'. Then the dealer tries to draw cards and beat the player's total without going over 21.

What i am wondering is what is the probability that the player wins the game? Also what would be the best number to stop drawing further cards as the player?

Comment: I would guess that this is a bit to complicated to solve completely. Maybe you should rather program a simulation and let in run a few million times.

Comment: Possible. I'll get started but i'd appreciate if a more accurate mathematical answer was possible. Random simulations are bound to give errors and the difference will probably be a small amount only.

Comment: Simulations are finished, interesting results.. It seems even the highest is around 17 where accepting any number equal to or greater than it is cause to 'stand'. But even so, only a 40 percent probability of victory exists